# Redirect http to https with www

Tags: wordpress, redirect, https

I am trying to find out how to redirect everything (http/ with and without and http: without) to https://www. (with www.)

I know it needs to be written in the `.htacess` file and I have forces admin to use https in `wp-config` already. I'm after the exact script to add at the top of my `.htacess` file please.

I am running on `Cpanel`. I'm using `wordpress` and `maxcdn` with `w3cache`. `maxcdn` is already set up for https.

I have found posts on how to write the code but lack the knowledge to create it myself.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Like Shiv said, `.htaccess` is definitely the way to go.  Here's the complete solution which will redirect to SSL and add www if not present:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this might do the trick:

```
# 301 Redirect 1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.domain.com/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]

# 301 Redirect 2
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.domain.com/? [R=301,NE,NC,L]
```

Obviously change domain.com to your domain name.

Comment: This would end up in an infinite redirect with the second portion

Comment: I see. I tested this on a domain without an SSL and it seemed to work (because of the non-secure warning?). After your comment I thought I would test it on a domain with SSL and you are correct...

Comment: No worries. See my solution above for the proper way of handling an or